# Mapping over an array in React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-query

I have a static data structure that I'm serving from my Next project's API route which is an array of objects with the following interface:

```js
export interface Case {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  beteiligte: string[];
  gerichtstermin?: string;
  tasks?: [];
}
```

I'm using React Query to pull in the data in a component:

```js
const Cases:React.FC = () => {
  const { data, status } = useQuery("cases", fetchCases);

  async function fetchCases() {
    const res = await fetch("/api/dummy-data");
    return res.json();
  }

  return (
    <DefaultLayout>
      <Loading loading={status === "loading"} />
      {data.cases.map((case)=><p>{case.name}</p>)}
    </DefaultLayout>
  );
}

export default Cases;
```

But when trying to map over the data I keep getting these squiggly lines and an incredibly ambiguous error:

[image]

[image]

I've tried absolutely everything I can think of and have searched far and wide through React Query documentation, typescript guides and of course many, many stackoverflow posts. Please help! (typescript newbie)

**UPDATE:**

When I type `{data.cases.map(()=>console.log("hello")}` there is no error at all. But as soon as I add a parameter to the anonymous function, the errors pop up: `{data.cases.map((case)=>console.log("hello"))}`

Comment: Try const { data: Case, status } =  useQuery("cases", fetchCases);

Comment: Types can't be assigned in an object like that as far as I know since this is javascript syntax for assigning a value to an object key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In the case interface, you do not have "name" property.
- you should be mapping only if `success` is `true`. you have to guard your code. see what you get `console.log(data)`. also, use `key` prop when mapping

  ```
  {status === "success" && (
      // case is reserved word. use a different name
      {data.cases.map((caseItem) => (
        <p key={caseItem.id}>{caseItem.name}</p>
      ))}
  )}
  ```
- `case` is a reserved word. If you use any other word it works

Comment: These are all very good suggestions, thank you. These are however general code improvement and don't address the issue I'm having 

Comment: @ChrisHaupt  `case` is a reserved word. that is why I guess

Comment: Seconded, `case` is likely the issue.

Comment: This was the issue, thank you so so much. Of course it is! I wish I'd read this answer before I spent the last half an hour recreating my project on Codesandbox  Thanks Yilmaz and everyone else!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue in sandbox and I managed to make it "transpile"

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/usequery-2022-10-1-5g0dz8?file=/src/MyComponent.tsx:719-784)

1. You have to add prop name of type string to the Case interface in order to use it

```js
export interface Case {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  title: string;
  beteiligte: string[];
  gerichtstermin?: string;
  tasks?: [];
}

// in my example interface is named CaseResonse
```

2. I assume your API response looks like this

```json
{ "data": { "cases": [] } }
```

3. You have to define the API response to be usable:

```js
interface GetCaseResponseWrapper {
  cases: Array<Case>;
}

// in my example it is array of CaseResponse
interface GetCaseResponseWrapper {
  cases: Array<CaseResponse>;
}
```

4. You need to decorate your fetchCases to return `GetCaseResponseWrapper`

```js
async function fetchCases() {
  const res = await fetch("/api/dummy-data");
  const jsonResult = await res.json();
  return jsonResult.data as GetCaseResponseWrapper;
}
```

5. the data from the useQuery may be undefined, so you should use ***?.***

```js
      {data?.cases.map((c) => (
        <p>{c.name}</p>
      ))}
```

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/usequery-2022-10-1-5g0dz8?file=/src/MyComponent.tsx:719-784)

Comment: Thank you so much for recreating this. After your proposed solution, I also created a sandbox to test, but your solution didn't work. It turns out it's just that the variable name `case` that I was using in the `array.map` is a reserved word in JS!